# Add Link On Specific Tag Post Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a text link to a specific "tag" post in Wordpress - click here - http://bit.ly/x9SfIG - I'm trying to add the link just below the "tag" title Drake. So the text would only be on this "tag" post - no others...I know I have to create a function...Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go sir:

```
<?php if(has_tag( 'drake' )) {
     echo ('<a href="%link destination%">Link Title</a>');
} ?>
```

This function checks to see if the post has the tag 'drake', and if it does, it'll show any link you specify in the above code. Just place it in your single.php file wherever you want the link to show.

Comment: Thanks I wil try this and let you know?

Comment: The above did not work...it added it to all blog posts not just drake

Comment: I did get it to work YEAH! I added it to the archieves.php - worked

Comment: Oh, okay, haha. I was gonna say, I just tried it myself and it worked : )

Comment: How about if I want to add some content along with the a few links...is it possible...I've tried some other content and does not work....just a link works but I want to add some content with it as well...any suggestions

Comment: I'm sorry Matt when adding content it worked just fine...I was having an issue with an Apostrophe (') in the file...just added a \ before the '

Comment: Matt...Do you know if it's possible to just add to a specific tag like the above but limit it to just the first page of the tag? So it would only hit the first tag page.